# How to share data securely between two Windows applications, not running at the same time?

Tags: windows, appsec

Scenario: Let's say I'm on a Windows machine. I have a data-driven uninstaller application that knows how to uninstall/remove various types of things (apps, files, etc...).

**Requirements**:

1. Rather than hardcode a list of things to uninstall in the app, I want the uninstaller to get lists of items to uninstall.
2. The "lists of items to uninstall" are produced by other Windows applications that can run when the uninstaller app isn't running.

**Question**: How can I securely share my "list of items to uninstall" between Windows applications that *aren't* running at the same time? I assert the registry might be the best place as it requires admin access. But, if I use the registry, should the text be encrypted as well, or is that overkill because I must be admin to see/modify it?

Comment: You have better chance with "superuser" than here :)

Comment: What does it need to be secure from?  Do you need to maintain confidentiality, or just integrity?  Are you protecting against regular users or malware?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian - My concerns are more on the integrity side. If someone can see the list, they could add additional items to it, for instance.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the exact model of WSUS or any other update server.